# Using apply functions instead of for and branching statements in R

Tags: r, lapply

I am using R and would like to stop using branching and for statements to take advantage of the apply functions.  That being said, I have this list, x:

x <- c(5,12,19,26,2,9,16,23)

I would like a corresponding list as follows:

```
for i in x
     if (i<=7) 1
     else if (i<=14) 2
     else if (i<=21) 3
     else if (i<=28) 4
     else 5
```

The final new list will be: 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4

How can I do this with one of the apply statements?  Every time I try and write one I end up scratching my head for an hour and then post a question here.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not something to do with `*apply` functions. You could use a nested `ifelse` (which is vectorised), but there are better possibilities.

Comment: @Roland, but `ifelse` won't work here because there are several conditional statements, right? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @ddiez Note the word "nested".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `cut`:

```
x <- c(5, 12, 21, 35)

as.integer(cut(x, c(-Inf, 7, 14, 21, 28, Inf)))
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

Comment: Would this work `findInterval(x, c(-Inf, 7, 14, 21, 28, Inf)+1)`.

Comment: @akrun It depends on x being an integer vector, which I didn't want to assume.

Comment: Very clever Roland, thanks.  I was not aware of the cut function, but even if I was, I probably wouldn't have though of using it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Showing ifelse use:

```
ifelse(x<7,1,ifelse(x<14,2,ifelse(x<21,3,ifelse(x<28,4,5))))
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```