# Using Branching Statements on entire list rather than individual items in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

This is a follow-up to this question, though the question here is independent of that one, [Using apply functions instead of for and branching statements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769790/using-apply-functions-instead-of-for-and-branching-statements-in-r)

I have a data frame:

```
    Date       Close    Weekday        DayOfMonth
290 1991-02-22 365.65   Friday         22
295 1991-03-01 370.47   Friday          1
300 1991-03-08 374.95   Friday          8
305 1991-03-15 373.59   Friday         15
310 1991-03-22 367.48   Friday         22
314 1991-03-28 375.22 Thursday         28
319 1991-04-05 375.36   Friday          5
324 1991-04-12 380.40   Friday         12
329 1991-04-19 384.20   Friday         19
334 1991-04-26 379.02   Friday         26
339 1991-05-03 380.80   Friday          3
```

I want to create another column called WeekOfCycle which figures out what week of the month a given date is in based on the day of the month.  I am using this function based on the aforementioned question.

```
as.integer(cut(data$DayOfMonth, c(-Inf, 7, 14, 21, 28, Inf)))
```

The above line is good for Fridays, for Thursdays it should be

```
as.integer(cut(data$DayOfMonth, c(-Inf, 6, 13, 20, 27, Inf)))
```

Desired output:

```
          Date  Close  Weekday DayOfMonth WeekOfCycle
290 1991-02-22 365.65   Friday         22           4
295 1991-03-01 370.47   Friday          1           1
300 1991-03-08 374.95   Friday          8           2
305 1991-03-15 373.59   Friday         15           3
310 1991-03-22 367.48   Friday         22           4
314 1991-03-28 375.22 Thursday         28           5
319 1991-04-05 375.36   Friday          5           1
324 1991-04-12 380.40   Friday         12           2
329 1991-04-19 384.20   Friday         19           3
334 1991-04-26 379.02   Friday         26           4
339 1991-05-03 380.80   Friday          3           1
```

I have tried to get this to work with this lapply function though it doesn't work:

```
   data$WeekOfCycle <- with(data, lapply(Weekday, function(i){
                            if (i == "Friday"){
                               as.integer(cut(DayOfMonth, c(-Inf, 7, 14, 21, 28, Inf)))
                               }
                            else if (i == "Thursday"){
                              as.integer(cut(DayOfMonth, c(-Inf, 6, 13, 20, 27, Inf)))
                            }
                            }
                           ))
```

I feel like I am close, but am definitely missing something.  Ideally, I'd like to do this even without the if and else statement but I don't know how.

Reproducible code for the data frame:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(7722, 7729, 7736, 7743, 7750, 
7756, 7764, 7771, 7778, 7785, 7792), class = "Date"), Close = c(365.65, 
370.47, 374.95, 373.59, 367.48, 375.22, 375.36, 380.4, 384.2, 
379.02, 380.8), Weekday = c("Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Friday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Friday"), DayOfMonth = c(22, 1, 8, 15, 22, 28, 5, 12, 19, 26, 
3)), .Names = c("Date", "Close", "Weekday", "DayOfMonth"), row.names = c(290L, 
295L, 300L, 305L, 310L, 314L, 319L, 324L, 329L, 334L, 339L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you included the desired output for your sample data so I can check whether i'm getting the results you desire, But how about this method

```
#define the shift for each week day
offset<-c(Friday=0, Thursday=1)

#see how may times 7 does into the date of month
MonthWeek <- unname((data$DayOfMonth+offset[data$Weekday]-1) %/% 7 +1)

cbind(data, MonthWeek)
#           Date  Close  Weekday DayOfMonth MonthWeek
# 290 1991-02-22 365.65   Friday         22         4
# 295 1991-03-01 370.47   Friday          1         1
# 300 1991-03-08 374.95   Friday          8         2
# 305 1991-03-15 373.59   Friday         15         3
# 310 1991-03-22 367.48   Friday         22         4
# 314 1991-03-28 375.22 Thursday         28         5
# 319 1991-04-05 375.36   Friday          5         1
# 324 1991-04-12 380.40   Friday         12         2
# 329 1991-04-19 384.20   Friday         19         3
# 334 1991-04-26 379.02   Friday         26         4
# 339 1991-05-03 380.80   Friday          3         1
```

In this particular cases, there is no need for complicated `if` statements. Everything can be done quickly with some pretty simple math.

Comment: I think you are on to it MrFlick.  Though I believe the offset needs to be added rather than subtracted.  Also, I am not sure that subtracting 1 is necessary.  In English, I want to know what Friday it is of the month, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th.  In the event that the data point is a Thurs, I am still interested in the Friday.  For example, in the data set above, there is Thurs, 3/28/91.  That is the 4th thurs of the month, but the next day is the 5th Friday, and it is the number 5 that I want.

Comment: Nicola, that won't work for Thursdays.  Even if the data point is a Thurs, I want to know what week of the month it is based on Fri.

Comment: @user2926358 I don't get it. Looking at a calendar for Match 1991, 03-28 is the 4th thursday. not the 5th

Comment: Yes, but Fri 3/29 is the 5th Friday.  That is what I want to know even in the instance where the weekly data point I have is a Thurs.

Comment: Ok, I think  it should be `(data$DayOfMonth-1) %/% 7 +1`. In this way the 7th day of the month is still week 1

Comment: @user2926358 I've updated with just adding the offset, and I think that does it. Unless i'm missing something it matches your desired output.

Comment: This is the line I am using and it is working, unname((DayOfMonth+offset[Weekday]) %/% 7 +1).  Thank you MrFlick for more than pointing me in the right direction.  I would never have thought of creating the offset using a named list.

Comment: @user2926358 Without the -1, i think that will fail for a date like `1993-05-07`.

Comment: You are correct.  This is also why I didn't want to do it with math, but in the end, It is probably the best way.  I built a sheet in excel with a smaller data set and did it using nested if statements, but I don't want to do that in R.